# Is there a way to detect all user generated events (click, keypress, ...) in Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, mobile

I'll be developing something for a Windows Mobile device using CompactFramework/C#.
I wonder if there is some event available that can capture any user driven event (click, keypress, ...) in context of the device. Sure, I could add some detection code in any of my click event handler for example but I assume that there hundreds of them.

So is there some event or windows  mobile API related call that could help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture keyboard events device-wide [via hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) (be aware that they are officially unsupported and so could disappear at any future release - though they've been there as long as I've been using CE, which is a *long* time).  We actually added [keyboard hook support](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/42824e9f-8a04-8cf8-ecf4-65429555cab9.htm) to the latest version of [the SDF](http://smartdeviceframework.com) if you're after something pre-built or for code. Mouse events, however, are not hookable in CE unless you write a new touch panel driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept key presses using the [Microsoft.WindowsCE.Form.MessageWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow.aspx) class. It is impossible to intercept click events.

Comment: That will only receive events send to your process, not device-wide.